# MySQLdb cursor()

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

I followed someone else's example to create this environmental data logger, but I feel like I'm being really inefficient. I open the connection once. I keep creating cursor objects (are they even necessary for this purpose?) and I'm afraid I'll eventually have massive numbers of cursor objects instantiated. On the other hand, I don't know how to deallocate a cursor object (does c.close() do that?)

My experience with other languages is that the connection object has an "execute" method for queries that have no return like this one. Advice?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT
import MySQLdb
import time

conn=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="xxxxxx5",db="EnviroLogger")

while True:

    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)
    temperaturef=((temperature*9)/5)+32
    datatime=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime())
    c=conn.cursor()
    c.execute ("INSERT INTO ResDataLog(ID,Location,Temperature, Humidity, RecDate) VALUES(null,'8200-Crawl',"+str(temperaturef)+","+str(humidity)+",'"+datatime+"');")
    print 'Temp: {0:0.1f} F  Humidity: {1:0.1f} % @ '.format(temperaturef, humidity),datatime
    conn.commit()
    time.sleep(600) #10 minutes
```

Comment: Can't you have one `cursor` object and then just do `c.execute()` in your loop? I doubt that this code is wasting much memory because all unused objects are deleted automatically by the garbage collector.

Comment: Yes, I changed it to stop closing the cursor and re-instantiating it. Works fine. Thanx.